# calculate the average in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, fasta

I have a fasta file with a sequences (file with text) like:

file.fasta

```
>seq_1
AGCTAATACTTGTCCACGTTGTACTTCTTCACGAGAAACACCACGTAATAAAGCACCGAT
GTTATCTCCAGCTTCAGCGTAATCTAATAATTTACGGAACATTTCTACACCTGTAACTGT
AGTTTTAGCTGGCTCTTCAGTTAAACCGATGATTTCAACTTCTTCACCAACTTTAACTTG
TCCACGCTCAACACGTCCAGTTGCAACTGTACCACGACCAGTGATTGAGAATACGTCCTC
AACTGGCATCATGAATGGTTTGTCAGAATCACGTTCTGGAGTTGGGATGTACTCATCAAC
TGCGTTCATTAATTCCATGATTTTTTCTTCGTACTCTTCAACGCCTTCTAATGCTTTTAA
AGCAGATCCAGCGATTACAGGTACATCGTCACCAGGGAAGTCATATTCAGATAATAAGTC
ACGAACTTCC
>seq_2
AGCTAATACTTGTCCACGTTGTACTTCTTCACGAGAAACACCACGTAATAAAGCACCGAT
GTTATCTCCAGCTTCAGCGTAATCTAATAATTTACGGAACATTTCTACACCTGTAACTGT
AGTTTTAGATGGCTCTTCAGTTAAACCGATGATTTCAACTTCTTCACCAACTTTAACTTG
TCCACGCTCAACACGTCCAGTTGCAACTGTACCACGACCAGTGATTGAGAATACGTCCTC
AACTGGCATCATGAATGGTTTGTCAGAATCACGTTCTGGAGTTGGGATGTACTCATCAAC
TGCGTTCATTAATTCCATGATTTTATCTTCGTACTCTTCAACGCCTTCTAATGCTTTTAA
AGCAGATCCAGCGATTACAGGTACATCGTCACCAGGGAAGTCATATTCAGATAATAAGTC
ACGAACTTCC
>seq_3
AGCTAATACTTGTCCACGTTGTACTTCTTCACGAGAAACACCACGTAATAAAGCACCGAT
GTTATCTCCAGCTTCAGCGTAATCTAATAATTTACGGAACATTTCTACACCTGTAACTGT
AGTTTTAGATGGCTCTTCAGTTAAACCGATGATTTCAACTTCTTCACCAACTTTAACTTG
TCCACGCTCAACACGTCCAGTTGCAACTGTACCACGACCAGTGATTGAGAATACGTCCTC
AACTGGCATCATGAATGGTTTGTCAGAATCACGTTCTGGAGTTGGGATGTACTCATCAAC
TGCATTCATTAATTCCATGATTTTATCTTCGTACTCTTCAACGCCTTCTAATGCTTTTAA
AGCAGATCCAGCGATTACAGGTACATCGTCACCAGGGAAGTCATATTCAGATAATAAGTC
ACGAACTTCC

............
>seq_n
AGCAGATCCAGCGATTACAGGTACATCGTCACCAGGGAAGTCATATTCAGATAATAAGTC
..............
```

So I want to calculate the average length of the strings avoiding the lines with `>seq_`, my code to obtain the length of each line is:

```
array_length=$(awk '/^>/ {print n $0; n="\n"}; !/^>/ {printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' My_file.fasta | awk '!/^>/ {print length(), $0}' | sort -n| awk '{print $1}')
```

until here everything is ok, I got the fist column that correspond to the length of each string:

```
echo "$array_length"

203
207
222
231
232
243
255
258
261
268
279
291
307
316

.....

161581
208146
242398
259601
288468
301866
427209
531340
557978
840257
```

well the length in the array could be variable, in this case I just show part of them.

my problem is that I want to calculate the average of the $array_length (sum of all numbers/length of the array)

A second question is how to take the fist element of the array and the last one; in order to do that, I just add a `tail -1` and `head -n 1` to the end of the code

```
awk '/^>/ {print n $0; n="\n"}; !/^>/ {printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' My_file.fasta | awk '!/^>/ {print length(), $0}' | sort -n| awk '{print $1}' | tail -1
awk '/^>/ {print n $0; n="\n"}; !/^>/ {printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' My_file.fasta | awk '!/^>/ {print length(), $0}' | sort -n| awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1
```

I know that, with a file I do it like

```
cat file.txt | tail -1
cat file.txt | head -n 1
```

But I dont want to use the same code twice to obtain the `$small_one` (203) and `$big_one` (840257), I just want to take the fist and last element of the variable `$array_length` like the one that I show here, how can I do it?

Comment: Note that for a large file, `cat file.txt | tail -n 1` is **vastly** slower than `tail -n 1 file.txt` or `tail -n 1 <file.txt`. When you use `cat`, you force the file to be read from the beginning, whereas when `tail` has a direct file handle it can jump straight to the end.

Comment: Anyhow -- as I read it, this question isn't about calculating averages so much as it's about efficiently getting both the first and last line of a file while reading it only once -- correct?

Comment: (if those are two separate questions, they should be **asked** as two separate questions; putting two unrelated questions in one Stack Overflow question is against the rules, and means that one question can be closed as "too broad")

Comment: ...that said, as a quick answer for the second question: `{ IFS= read -r first; last=$(tail -n 1); } <file.txt; echo "First line is $first; last line is $last"`. If your `file.txt` is instead a pipeline, use `< <(...)` where `...` is the pipeline content instead of `<file.txt`.

Comment: @biqarboy, btw -- the edit you proposed is itself a good one, but the first edit to a closed question puts it into the review queue for reopening, so ideally the first edit to a closed question should be sufficient to bring it within site rules so it can actually be reopened; otherwise, that one "free" reopen-queue chance has potential to be wasted.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Thank you! I got it now. I actually did not notice that this post was closed. It's really bad wasting `re-open queue slot`. Sorry for the inconvenience.